# security exception opening Provider Urbanairship

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have no  idea why I'm getting this exception, here is log cat:

```
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider from ProcessRecord{40c16f78 2825:package:location_service/10206} (pid=2825, uid=10206) that is not exported from uid 10107
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1321)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1275)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2014)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.getProvider(ActivityThread.java:3673)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:3698)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:1565)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:909)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:296)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipResolver.query(Unknown Source)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at com.urbanairship.PreferencesResolver.get(Unknown Source)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at com.urbanairship.Preferences.getPreferenceFromDatabase(Unknown Source)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at com.urbanairship.Preferences.getPreference(Unknown Source)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at com.urbanairship.Preferences.getBoolean(Unknown Source)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at com.urbanairship.push.PushPreferences.isAPIDReady(Unknown Source)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.getAPID(Unknown Source)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at com.urbanairship.UAirship.takeOff(Unknown Source)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at package.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:157)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:968)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3598)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1040)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-19 12:19:17.840: W/System.err(2825):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm  getting this error when I restart device. I have my Application on Market, Tested on motorola Xoom.

Please help ...

Comment: Did you add urbanairship provider class with your package name in AndroidManifest file? `<provider android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider" android:authorities="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.urbanairship.provider"/>`

Comment: yes I did. I observed basic things like If I use 
PushPreferences prefs = PushManager.shared().getPreferences();
    apid = prefs.getPushId(); In my Location Service. I also get this error there when My service starts with device boot.

Comment: You could drop a mail to urbanairship.. Hopefully you will get some pointers...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be running two processes. If possible, run everything in a single process, because there are bugs in some versions of Android that cause things like this. If you absolutely need two processes, all urban airship code should run in a single process (the main process), and the Application.onCreate method should not call UAirship.takeOff in the second process.